# Not able to Populate the Second Dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Why is that everytime I select from the Country it does not populate the list of states in that specific country. I have two tables on this one for country and another one for states.

```
private $_table = "tbl_country";
        ## MY MODEL ##
        function get_by_id($id)
          {
            $query = $this->db->get_where($this->_table, "ID = $id");

            $data = $query->row();
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;
          }

         function fetchCountry()
          {
            $this->db->select('Country');
            $this->db->from('tbl_country');
            $this->db->order_by('Country', "asc");
            $get = $this->db->get();
            return $get->result_Array();
          }

          function fetchState($data)
          {
            $this->db->select('State');
            $this->db->from('tbl_state');
            $this->db->where($data);
            $this->db->order_by('State', "asc");
            $get = $this->db->get();
            return $get->result_Array();
          }
```

1. Here's my view php

```
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Country</label>
        <?= form_dropdown('Country', [
            ''  => '--Select Country--',
            'United States' => 'United States'
            ], set_value('Country', @$rs->Country? $rs->Country: ''), 'class="form-control"id="Country"') ?>
        <?= form_error('Country') ?>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>State</label>
        <select name="State" id="State" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected disabled>--Select State--</option>
        </select>
```

2. Controller

   function showCountry()
       {
           $result = $this->country_m->fetchCountry();
           echo json_encode($result);
       }

   ```
   function showState()
   {
       $data = $this->input->post();
       $result = $this->country_m->fetchState($data);
       echo json_encode($result);
   }
   ```

Comment: is your query is correct to populate sates.. Please print out query by $this->db->last_query();.. And run the printed query in phpmyadmib..

Comment: the data still not display based on the first dropdown

Comment: you have to do ajax request for dependent dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You wont get it in that way .You have to use Ajax functionality as those are dependent dropdowns .